# Aggregation pipeline $set a value to boolean whether $and is true or false

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, conditional-statements, aggregate

In my aggregation pipeline, I am trying to set a value to `true` if several conditions are matched. I will be adding more `$and` conditions later, but it doesn't even work with one condition.

These are the things I have tried:

```json
    {
      $set: {
        someValue: {
          $and: [
            {
              'ratePlans.maxAdvBookDays': {
                $gte: advBookDays,
              },
            },
          ],
        }
      }
    }
```

```json
    {
      $set: {
        someValue: {
          $and: [
            {
              $toBool: {
                'ratePlans.maxAdvBookDays': {
                  $gte: advBookDays,
                },
              },
            }
          ],
        }
      }
    }
```

```json
    {
      $set: {
        someValue: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $and: [
                {
                  'ratePlans.maxAdvBookDays': {
                    $gte: advBookDays,
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
            then: 'then',
            else: 'else',
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

In each case, I get the following error:

> MongoServerError: Invalid $set :: caused by :: FieldPath field names may not contain '.'.

However, when hard-coding the boolean values in, it **does** seem to work:

```
    {
      $set: {
        someValue: {
          $and: [
            true, true, false, true
          ],
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      someValue: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $and: [
              {
                $gte: [ "$ratePlans.maxAdvBookDays", 2 ]
              }
            ]
          },
          then: "then",
          else: "else"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lWuyAw3ksQA)